# How do I implement a recursive and extensible Twig template?

Tags: templates, twig

I'm implementing a simple website menu, but this time I'm using Twig as my template language. The depth of the menu tree is one or greater. Here's my Twig code so far (sanitized and simplified):

```
{# file menu1.html.twig #}
<ul>
    {% import _self as renderer %}
    {% for item in menu.items %}
        {{ renderer.renderItem(item) }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% macro renderItem(item) %}
    {% block itemtag %}
    <li>
    {% endblock %}
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
        {% if item.hasItems() %}
            <ul>
                {% import _self as renderer %}
                {% for subitem in item.items %}
                    {{ renderer.renderItem(subitem) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endmacro %}
```

Now I need to override the "itemtag" element in another template:

```
{# file menu2.html.twig #}
{% extends "menu1.html.twig" %}

    {% block itemtag %}
    <li data-foo="bar">
    {% endblock %}
```

This will not work, as explained very well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26650103/220817

So how do I write a Twig template that can traverse and render a tree structure, and still allow extending templates to override certain elements in the rendered markup?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use macro's if you want to do something recursive as macro's can self import themself. Here is an example of a recursive macro:

```
{% macro menu(m, class, currentLevel, maxLevel) %}
    {%if not class is defined %}
        {% set class = '' %}
    {% endif %}
    {%if not currentLevel is defined or currentLevel is null %}
        {% set currentLevel = 1 %}
    {% endif %} 
    {%if m is iterable%}
        {% set links = m %}
    {% else %}
        {% set links = m.getLinks() %}
        {% if m.showRoot() and m.hasRoot() %}
        <li class="root{%if class != ''%} {{class}}{%endif%}">
            <a href="{%if m.getRoot().getTreeLeft() > 1 %}{{ m.getRoot().getRoute() }}{% else %}#site_url#{% endif %}" {% if m.getRoot().PageId in selected_page_ids  %} class="selected"{% endif %}>{{ m.getRoot().name }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if maxLevel is null %}{% set maxLevel = m.getLevel() %}{% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if not links is empty %}
        {% for link in links %}
            {% if link['selected'] is defined and link['selected'] %}
                {% set is_selected = true %}
            {% else %}
                {% set is_selected = false %}
            {% endif %}

            {% set anchor_class = '' %}
            {% if link.PageId in selected_page_ids or is_selected %}
                {% set anchor_class='selected' %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if method_exists(link, 'getPageCssClass') and link.getPageCssClass() != null %}
                {% set class= class~' '~link.getPageCssClass().getTitle() %}
            {% endif %}

            <li{%if (class|trim) != '' %} class="{{ (class|trim) }}"{% endif %}>
                <a href="{{ link.getRoute }}"{%if (anchor_class|trim) != '' %} class="{{ (anchor_class|trim) }}" {% endif %} {% if link.PageId  > 0 %}data-page-id="{{ link.PageId  }}"{% endif %}>{{ link.name }}</a>
                {% if link.hasPublicChildren and currentLevel < maxLevel %}
                    <ul>
                        {{ _self.menu(link.getPublicChildren, 'sec', (currentLevel+1), maxLevel) }}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: So if I wanted to extend the template you've got here and simply add an attribute to the anchor tag (e.g. <a data-foo="bar" ... >), how would I do that?

Comment: Imho best place for that is set an array attributes in the link object/array which you then can loop with {% for key,value in link.attributes %}{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endfor %}